# How do I calculate the distance among all points in set in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix

I am a very new user of any GIS.  In QGIS I have input my UTM data as a CSV file.  Under *Vector* -> *Analysis Tools* -> *Distance Matrix*, I have been able to create a distance matrix but it just takes one point and calculates the distance to each other point.  I want the distance between all possible points. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Late post but what you mentioned should yield you distances from **each** point to **every** other point.

I did a quick test by importing points from a CSV via *Add Delimited Text Layer...*. I then **saved** this as a shapefile. This is probably what happened to you, if you do not save it then it will only take the last point of the attribute table to analyse. Here is a screenshot of my attributes:

[image: Point layer example]

I then selected the same layer when running the *Distance Matrix* tool:

[image: Distance matrix]

And here is my final result, I dragged the csv file to the QGIS interface:

[image: Attribute result]

Hope this helps (although you probably forgot about this question!)